# javascript object property applying for all object

Tags: javascript

## this is my html

```
    <!-- language: lang-js -->
    window.onload = function(){
    var a = new color(document.getElementById('red'),{weight:'bold'});
    var b = new color(document.getElementById('green'));
    }
```

## this is my javascript

```
    <!-- language: lang-js -->
    (function (w) {
    function obj(element, source) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = this.extend(this.defaults, source);
        this._init();
        console.log(this.defaults);
    }
    obj.prototype = {
        extend: function (destination, source) {
            for(var k in source) {
                if(source.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                    destination[k] = source[k];
                }
            }
            return destination;
        },
        defaults: {
            color: 'red'
        },
        _init: function () {
            this.element.style.color = this.options.color;
            if(this.options.weight) {
                this.element.style.fontWeight = this.options.weight;
            }
            this._initEvent();
        },
        _initEvent: function () {
            var o = this;
            this.element.onmouseover = function () {
                o._mouseOver(this);
            }
            this.element.onmouseout = function () {
                o._mouseOut(this);
            }
        },
        _mouseOver: function (j) {
            j.style.border = "1px solid " + this.options.color;
        },
        _mouseOut: function (j) {
            j.style.border = "1px solid transparent";
        }
    }
    w.color = obj;
})(window)
```

## this is my resutls

```
<p>Object { color="red", weight="bold"}</p>
<p>Object { color="red", weight="bold"}</p>
```

## My proplem

My issue is here, i have given `weight:bold` property only for object "a". but it is applying object "b" also. it should be applied only for "a". please help me to sort out this issue

Comment: Oh, common. You expect us to read compressed JavaScript to help you? You should be doing your best to make it *easy* to help you, not posting obfuscated code...

Comment: hi sridhra, i am new to stackoverflow. i tried lot. but i could not format the code properly...<br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating a shared object on the prototype so it'll mutate for all instances, to prevent that you can do the following:

```
function obj(element, source) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = this.extend({color:"red"}, source);
    this._init();
    console.log(this.defaults);
}
```

There is another solutions where you keep defaults:

```
function obj(element, source) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = this.extend({}, this.defaults);
    this.extend(this.options, source);//extend will mutate this.options
    this._init();
    console.log(this.defaults);
}
```

For more information on prototype see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).